# GloriaFood PHP CURL API

Tags: php, php-curl

I have no idea why my PHP Curl API unable to retrieve the data from the "Accepted Orders" even though the response status code is 200 and the response body is 0.

**Code:**

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, [
 CURLOPT_URL => "https://pos.globalfoodsoft.com/pos/order/pop",
 CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
 CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
 CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
 CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
 CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
 CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
 CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
   "Accept: application/json",
   "Authorization: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
   "Glf-Api-Version: 2"
 ],
]);

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);
```

**Body**

> {
> "count": 0,
> "orders": []
> }

However, the same Curl API is able to retrieve the data in the "Fetch Menu".

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, [
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://pos.globalfoodsoft.com/pos/menu",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
    "Accept: application/json",
    "Authorization: XXXXXXX",
    "Glf-Api-Version: 2"
  ],
]);

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

REF - API Docs: https://github.com/GlobalFood/integration_docs

Comment: Looks like https://github.com/GlobalFood/integration_docs/issues/14 which was raised last year with no response.